# Java - Delete Node From Doubly Linked List

Tags: java, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I'm trying to understand how Linked List data structures works, but in the past week after researching it and watching tutorials, I'm still confused. I'm trying to delete a node, when a node is not the head or the tail.

I'm working with a doubly linked list

My Linked List: **[A]=[B]=[C]=[D]=[E]=[F]**

I'm trying to delete Node B

This is my delete method

```
public GNode deleteNode(E e) {

    GNode temp = new GNode(e); // This gets Node: [B]
    GNode tempNext = temp.getNext(); // This gets Node: [C]
    GNode tempPrevious = temp.getPrevious(); // This get Node: [A]
    GNode current = findNode(temp, e); // This finds Node: [B]

    // Deletes Head
    if (this.head.getData().equals(e)) {
        head = head.next;
        head.previous = null;
        this.size--;
    }

    // Delete Tail
    if (this.tail.getData().equals(e)) {
        tail = tail.previous;
        tail.next = null;
        this.size--;
    } 
     // Delete Node 
    else {
        if(findNode(temp,e) == e){
        System.out.println("VALUE: " + temp.next);// Using this to debug. BUT temp.next returns null !?
        tempPrevious.setNext(tempNext);
        tempNext.setPrevious(tempPrevious);
        size--;
        }
    }

    return temp;
}
```

By doing some debugging I think I may not be initializing my variables correctly or looping through the list. Would anybody be able to point me to the right direction? And see what I may be doing wrong?

This is the entire code I'm working with

```
import java.io.*;

import java.util.*;

public class GDList<E> implements Cloneable {

private static class GNode<E> {
    private E data;
    private GNode<E> previous;
    private GNode<E> next;

    public GNode(E e) {
        data = e;
        previous = null;
        next = null;
    }

    public E getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public GNode getPrevious() {
        return previous;
    }

    public GNode getNext() {
        return next;
    }

    public void setData(E e) {
        data = e;
    }

    public void setPrevious(GNode p) {
        previous = p;
    }

    public void setNext(GNode p) {
        next = p;
    }

    public Iterator<String> iterator() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
}

private GNode<E> head;
private GNode<E> tail;
private int size; // number of nodes in a list

public GDList() {
    head = null;
    tail = null;
    size = 0;
}

public int addToHead(E e) {
    GNode temp = new GNode(e);
    if (head == null) {
        head = temp;
        tail = temp;
    } else {
        if (findNode(head, e) == null) {
            temp.setNext(head);
            head.setPrevious(temp);
            head = temp;
        } else
            return 1;
    }
    size++;
    return 0;
}

public int addToTail(E e) {

    GNode temp = new GNode(e);
    if (head == null) {
        head = temp;
        tail = temp;
    } else {
        if (findNode(head, e) == null) {
            temp.setPrevious(tail);
            tail.setNext(temp);
            tail = temp;
        } else
            return 1;
    }
    size++;
    return 0;
}

public int addAfter(GNode n, E e) {

    if (n == null)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("The node n cannot be null");

    if (findNode(head, e) != null)
        return 1;
    if (n == tail) {
        addToTail(e);
    } else {
        GNode temp = new GNode(e); // element
        GNode tempNext = n.getNext(); // location of element
        temp.setNext(tempNext); // set element to the next location where
                                // the position is null
        tempNext.setPrevious(temp); //
        temp.setPrevious(n);
        n.setNext(temp);
        size++;
    }
    return 0;
}

public int addBefore(GNode n, E e) {

    if (n == null)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("The node n c6annot be null");

    if (findNode(head, e) != null)
        return 1;
    if (n == head)
        addToHead(e);
    else {
        GNode temp = new GNode(e);
        GNode tempPrevious = n.getPrevious();
        temp.setNext(n);
        n.setPrevious(temp);
        tempPrevious.setNext(temp);
        temp.setPrevious(tempPrevious);
        size++;
    }
    return 0;
}


@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public GNode deleteNode(E e) {

    // Linked List [22]=[3]=[17]=[9]

    GNode prevNode = this.head;

    GNode temp = new GNode(e); // Node: [17]
    GNode tempNext = temp.getNext(); // Node: [9]
    GNode tempPrevious = temp.getPrevious(); // Node: [3]
    GNode current = findNode(temp, e); // Node: [17]

    // Deletes Head
    if (this.head.getData().equals(e)) {
        head = head.next;
        head.previous = null;
        this.size--;
    }

    // Delete Tail
    if (this.tail.getData().equals(e)) {
        tail = tail.previous;
        tail.next = null;
        this.size--;
    } 

    else {
        if(findNode(temp,e) == e){
        System.out.println("VALUE: " + temp.next);// Using this to debug. BUT temp.next returns null !?
        tempPrevious.setNext(tempNext);
        tempNext.setPrevious(tempPrevious);
        size--;
        }
    }

    return temp;
}

public GNode deleteAfter(E e) {
    GNode temp = findNode(head, e);
    if (temp == tail || temp == null)
        return null;
    return (deleteNode((E) temp.getNext().data));
}


public GNode deleteBefore(E e) {
    GNode temp = findNode(head, e);
    if (temp == head || temp == null)
        return null;
    return (deleteNode((E) temp.getPrevious().data));
}

public GNode findNode(GNode p, E e) {
    GNode current = p; // current is the cursor
    while (current != null && current.data != e) // while is not what I'm
                                                    // looking for
        current = current.getNext();
    return current;
}


public void printList() {
    System.out.print("Number of nodes = " + size + ", List is: ");
    if (head != null) {
        GNode current = head;
        while (current != null) {
            System.out.print(current.data + " ");
            current = current.getNext();
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("The list is empty");
    }
    System.out.println();
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    GDList<String> names = new GDList<String>();

    names.printList();
    names.addToTail("A");
    names.addToTail("B");
    names.addToTail("C");
    names.addToTail("D");
    names.addToTail("E");
    names.addToTail("F");

    System.out.println();

    // Delete Node 
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("\nDelete Node");
    names.printList();
    names.deleteNode("B"); // Delete B
    names.printList();

}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a new object `GNode temp = new GNode(e);`, temp.next and temp.previous is set to null. You can look at the constructor here.

```
public GNode(E e) {
    data = e;
    previous = null;
    next = null;
}
```

You already have a method called findNode which is gonna simplify a lot of it.

```
public GNode deleteNode(E e) {

    GNode current = findNode(head, e); // This finds Node: [B]

    // a node with data e doesn't exist
    if (current == null) {
        return null;
    }

    // get the next and previous node
    GNode previous = current.previous;
    GNode next = current.next;

    // current node is head
    if (previous == null) {
        this.head = current.next;
        this.head.previous = null;
    }

    // current node is tail
    if (next == null) {
        this.tail = current.previous;
        this.tail.next = null;
    }

    if (previous != null || next != null) {
        GNode temp = current.previous;
        temp.next = current.next;
        temp = current.next;
        temp.previous = current.previous;
    }

    return current;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried this code but it returns a null pointer error. When you're using `current = findNode(temp, e);` I still have to initialize `temp`? Sorry if my question doesn't make sense. I'm new to Java and I've been struggling with this for longer than I had hoped for.

Comment: Nevermind, I changed it to  `GNode current = findNode(head, e); // This finds Node: [B]` and it works now. Thanks again!

Comment: My bad. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: does this code not break if there is only one node in the list -- head would be set to null and then in the next line `head.previous == null` will be a null pointer exception